# How much memory kmem_cache_create allocates?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am new in driver and stuck in memory management .
I went through  kmem_cache_create documentation but didin't find following answer to my doubts.

1. how much kmem_cache_create allocate
2. if for example it allocates x bytes then wht will happen if x number of bytes are allocated and driver call kmem_alloc?

Answer (score 0):

Initially, it allocates memory you passed in arguments (size). And later kmem_cache_alloc() go out it will automatically allocates more memory.